# How to put files on a server and remove the local copy using command line ftp

Tags: c#, batch-file, ftp, cmd

I am learning cmd line ftp and was wondering how i can transfer a file to a remote directory while simultaneously removing the local copy.

Is this possible ?

I don't wan't to transfer and then run a delete command, but so far all i have is:

```
mput *xml
```

Which doesn't remove the local copy

Answer (score 1):

You can execute arbitrary shell commands from within most command line ftp programs w/ a bang (`!`). So I guess you could do:

```
ftp> !pwd
/home/foo_user
ftp> mput *xml
ftp> ! rm *xml
```

But I think this might be kind of dangerous since you might inadvertently delete something important

Comment: right, what i was wanting was to move the file not copy it, but it looks like you can't do that apparently +1

Comment: @some_bloody_fool There is no such thing as "moving" a file. You can rename a file, which 'moves' it to a new location on the same media. Or you can copy and then delete which effectively performs a move.

Comment: That's not a solution. My understanding of what the OP meant by "moving" is to perform it atomically, either the file does get moved or it doesn't. Copy and delete is not an option, because both actions are atomic, and failure to copy does not prevent succesful delete, leading to data loss. You need to add some checks for file existence (pre and post) and for succesful copy operation.